# Splitting files by line across two files equally without pre-defined chunk length - Unix

Tags: bash, split, text-files, line

I have two files of equal length (i.e. no. of lines):

- text.en
- text.cs

I want to incrementally split the files into 12 parts and as I iterate, I need to add 1 out of the first ten part to it.

Let's say if I the files contain 100 lines, I need some sort of loop that does:

```
#!/bin/bash

F1=text.en
F2=text.cs

for i in `seq 0 9`;
do
    split -n l/12 -d text.en
    cat x10 > dev.en
    cat x11 > test.en
    echo "" > train.en
    for j in `seq 0 $i`; do
        cat x0$j >> train.en
    done

    split -n l/12 -d text.cs
    cat x10 > dev.cs
    cat x11 > test.cs
    echo "" > train.cs
    for j in `seq 0 $i`; do
        cat x0$j >> train.cs
    done

    wc -l train.en train.cs
    echo "############"
done
```

[out]:

```
   55632 train.en
   55468 train.cs
  111100 total
############
  110703 train.en
  110632 train.cs
  221335 total
############
  165795 train.en
  165011 train.cs
  330806 total
############
```

It's giving me unequal chunks between the files.

Also, when I use `split`, it's splitting into unequal chunks:

```
alvas@ubi:~/workspace/cvmt$ split -n l/12 -d text.en
alvas@ubi:~/workspace/cvmt$ wc -l x*
   55631 x00
   55071 x01
   55092 x02
   54350 x03
   54570 x04
   54114 x05
   55061 x06
   53432 x07
   52685 x08
   52443 x09
   52074 x10
   52082 x11
  646605 total
```

I don't know the no. of lines of the file before hand, so I can't use the `split -l` option.

**How do I split a file into equal size by no. of lines given that I don't know how many lines are there in the files beforehand? Should I do some sort of pre-calculation with `wc -l`?**

**How do I ensure that the split across two files are of equal size in for every chunk?**

(Note that the solution needs to split the file at the end of the lines, i.e. don't split up any lines, just split the file by line).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but here are a few pointers:

`split -n l/12` splits into 12 chunks of roughly equal *byte size*, not *number of lines*.

`split -n r/12` will *try* to distribute the *line count* evenly, but if the chunk size is not a divisor of the total line count, you'll still get (slightly) varying line counts: the *extra lines are distributed round-robin style*.

E.g., with 100 input lines and a line chunk size of 12, you'll get line counts of `9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8`: `100 / 12 = 8` (integer division), and `100 % 12 = 4`, so all files get *at least* `8` lines, with the extra 4 lines distributed among the first 4 output files.

So, yes, if you want a *fixed* line count for all files (except for the last, if the chunk size is not a divisor), you must calculate the total line count up front, perform integer division to get the fixed line count, and use `split -l` with that count:

```
 totalLines=$(wc -l < text.en)
 linesPerFile=$(( totalLines / 12 ))

 split -l 12 text.en # with 100 lines, yields 8 files with 12 and 1 with 4 lines
```

---

Additional observations:

With a small, fixed iteration count, it is easier and more efficient to use brace expansion (e.g., `for i in {0..9}` rather than `` for i in `seq 0 9` ``).

If a variable must be used, or with larger numbers, use an arithmetic expression:
`n=9; for (( i = 0; i <= $n; i++ )); do ...; done`

While you cannot do `cat x0{0..$i}` directly (because Bash doesn't support variables in brace expansions), you can emulate it by combining `seq -f` and `xargs`:

You can replace

```
echo "" > train.en
for j in `seq 0 $i`; do
    cat x0$j >> train.en
done
```

with the following:

```
seq -f 'x%02.f' "$i" | xargs cat > train.en
```

Since you control the value of `$i`, you could even simplify to:

```
eval "cat x0{0..$i}" > train.en  # !! Only do this if you trust $i to contain a number.
```

Comment: Cool! I have never thought of piping `seq | xargs`  =)